# Creating an EC2 instance from a snapshot in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it not possible to create an EC2 instance from a snapshot in AWS?

I tried to create volume, but then i was stuck starting an EC2 instance with that volume. Should that not be an easy process? I don't even know, if this way is  correct. I am just guessing.

What steps are necessary to create a EC2 instance only from the snapshot?

Comment: It is easy. Can you provide more details on what you have actually tried and why it did not work?

Comment: i just do not know the steps. i would expect something like "create ec2 instance from snapshot".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "create ec2 instance from snapshot"

Your almost there. The option is called "Create image". So:

1. Go to your snapshot.
2. Right click and choose "Create image" (assume the volume is bootable and it works).
3. Fill out the info required.
4. Image (aka AMI) will be created based on your snapshot and the info you will provide.
5. Launch an instance from the AMI.

More details in [Create a Linux AMI from a snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html#creating-launching-ami-from-snapshot).